# IE browser tab seems to freeze after repeated button clicks

Tags: c#, html, powershell, batch-file, internet-explorer

I have a simple HTML file with a button in which whenever I click it, it looks up to the registry and then runs a batch file. After a couple of clicks, I noticed it seems to freeze. Whenever I hover my cursor to the tab, it doesn't display details anymore. This part is crucial since I have to retrieve the description/details through `IAccessible`'s `accDescription`.

Also, I noticed that whenever this issue happens, whenever I click on the button, the action URL in my form will appear in the address bar for a split second and then goes back to default html file path. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head2" runat="server">
<title>Run Executable HTA</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="appts:THxJRXxodHRwczovL3d3dy5nb29nbGUuY29tLnBo">
    <input type="submit" value="Launch Portal to Left" />   
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your HTML code. The fact that it's loading in the address bar and then reverting could mean that there's a problem with the form's `action`. I'm assuming that `appts` is a protocol? In that case you need to affix two backslashes to it: `appts://TH...`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge it won't work when I put two backslashes. I'm really puzzled why the tab doesn't display the description. It works as if there's nothing wrong, it's just the description won't appear anymore and that's the one I need.